# In 6d, can I use the cross product between two sets of three coordinates as a good new coordinate, along with the modulus of the 6d coordinate vector?

Tags: calculus, manifolds, coordinate-systems

Consider a function $f(a_i)$ of 6 Cartesian variables $a_i$. In the presence of rotational symmetry, we say that $f$ really just depends on the modulus $r=|a|$ and, particularly if we wish to look for critical points, it suffices to consider $f(|a|)$; there is only one true degree of freedom.

I happen to have a function which can be written in terms of $r=|{a}|$ *as well as* $c=|\vec{a1}\times \vec{a2}|$, where $\vec{a1}=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and $\vec{a2}=(a_4,a_5,a_6)$:
$$f(r,c)=f(|a|,|\vec{a1}\times \vec{a2}|).$$
My question is, are there really just 2 degrees of freedom to my function, can I find all critical points by differentiating w.r.t. $r$ and $c$?

**My attempt:**

It seems to me to depend on whether I can make a coordinate transformation on 6d space $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6\}$ to a new coordinate system where two of the coordinates are $r$ and $c$ (the remaining 4 combinations of the initial $a_i$ not appearing in my function). What makes a good coord transformation? (After all not everything is allowed.. I can't simply call $f(a_i)$ itself a new coordinate to end up with a 1d problem). I believe the coordinate mapping needs to be 1-1 (and onto), at least in a network of overlapping open subsets.

Consider the candidate mapping
$$\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6\}\rightarrow \{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,r(a_i),c(a_i)\}$$
The mapping will be 1-1 if
$$a_{1,2,3,4}=b_{1,2,3,4} \quad \quad r(a_i)=r(b_i), \quad \quad c(a_i)=c(b_i)$$
$$\implies a_i = b_i$$
The equalities on $r$ and $c$ boil down to
$$a_5^2 + a_6^2 = b_5^2 + b_6^2, \quad \quad a_2 a_5 + a_3 a_6 = a_2 b_5 + a_3 b_6$$
and solving one has
$$ \left\{ b_5=a_5,\; b_6=a_6  \right\}\quad \text{or} \quad \left\{b_5=\frac{a_2^2 a_5 - a_3^2 a_5 + 2 a_2 a_3 a_6}{a_2^2 + a_3^2}, \; b_6=\frac{2 a_2 a_3 a_6 - a_2^2 a_6 + a_3^2 a_6}{a_2^2 + a_3^2}\right\}$$
Thus it would seem that transformation is not globally 1-1. However, even it could still perhaps be a good coordinate transformation using a network of overlapping open set 'patches', where only one of the two alternatives was valid. I'm not sure how to go about proving this.. and feel that maybe I am overcomplicating things...and there might be easier ways to realise if $r$ and $c$ are good variables..

Comment: If you rotate $a1$ and $a2$ in 3D, then the result stays the same, maybe you can use that. That's already 3 of the other 4 degrees of freedom.

Comment: I need to rotate them both by the exact same amount to keep the result the same. I could, say, rotate $a1$ to coincide with one of the axes, the $a_1$ direction, for example. So only two degrees of freedom disappear, if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: I suppose after rotating $\vec{a1}$ to coincide with the z-axis in 3D, I still have the freedom to rotate in x-y plane until $\vec{a2}$ is purely in the y-z plane. Then $\vec{a1}\times \vec{a2}=(a_3 a_5)$. Can I take this to mean that somehow $|\vec{a1}\times \vec{a2}|=|a_3 a_5|$ intrinsically contains 2 degrees of freedom? My worry is that I could define entirely new coordinates where $a_3 a_5$ is one of them and the others are some other combinations of the $a_i$ so that  $|\vec{a1}\times \vec{a2}|$ ends up containing one degree of freedom

Comment: I don't get everything you're saying and for me it's also complicated. But I think we're more or less on the same page. We can say $a_1 = a_2 = a_4 = 0, a_3 \ge 0, a_5 \ge 0$ for our initial vectors, these restrictions are allowed because we rotate later. We can give our new coordinate system parameters $r$, $c$, $a_3$ and three parameters for rotation. The equations $c = a_3 a_5$ and ${a_3}^2 + {a_5}^2 + {a_6}^2 = r^2$ need to be dealt with. You can visualize the solution to these equations as the intersection of a hyperbole (extended to 3D) and a sphere.

Comment: So if you go this way (don't know if it's the best approach), then the next thing to do is to figure out which combinations of $r, c, a_3$ are valid.